# Javascript to validate or filter Start and End times?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, time, fullcalendar

In a form I have one Date text field and 2 dropdowns: Start time and End Time with 30-minutes time interval.

1. One user selects time 9:00:00 - 11:00:00
2. The second user selects time 1:00:00 - 3:00:00
3. The Third user wants 8:00:00 - 16:00:00

The third user was able to select the time frame that overlaps with the first two users.

Is it possible to compare and validate these times using jquery?

The application is in asp.net mvc. It includes fullcalendar.js plugin.

Thank you very much for your advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to directly do this with jQuery, but this is the general algorithm I would use to solve this:

Assuming the smallest increment of time is an hour, every user selects a set of numbers, each number ranges from 0-23 (representing the hour). Then, if the first 2 users have selected sets A and B, then the third user should only be allowed to choose from the intersection of the two sets i.e A AND B. You can generalize this to any number of users.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to write an algorithm based on your suggestion. 
I was also wondering if it's possible to disable the past times (less then time is now) for selection in a dropdown. So I can select only times starting from current time. How is it possible? How can I filter the times and specify a condition? I'll appreciate your advise!

Comment: OK. I don't know about your platform, so I don't know how to get the current time. Assuming that you have the current time, rounded to the closest increment of time (say its 16), then you can use the same idea - create a set T which contains 16..23, and then take the intersection - A AND B .. AND Z .. AND T